# Package list for Kickstart

Tags: linux, kickstart

Is there anyway I can get the package list off of a live Linux box and put that into a kickstart?

---

Edit: Sorry...This is on a Fedora box

Comment: My answer still applies, as Fedora uses RPM for package management

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the common ones:

Debian/Ubuntu/Mint (for Debian/pkg type distros):

```
dpkg -l
```

(Incidentally, on Debian/Ubuntu, you use [preseed](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed))

For RedHat/CentOS/SuSE/Fedora (RedHat/RPM type distros):

```
rpm -qa
```

As a side note, if this is a relatively fresh install (no packages added after installation), you can use the ananconda-ks.cfg file and use that as base kickstart, as that contains the list of packages plus other configuration setting that was set and insatlled during the initial setup.

Answer (score 0):

For a shorter list, you can list the [package groups](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#Chapter_3._Package_Selection) with yum:

```
# yum grouplist
Loaded plugins: changelog, security
Setting up Group Process
Installed Groups:
   Base
   Desktop
   Desktop Platform
   Graphical Administration Tools
   Legacy UNIX compatibility
   Networking Tools
   Performance Tools
   Perl Support
   Web Server
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting a new answer, I don't have any reputation to comment.

`rpm -qa` is definitely going to be the way to go, but you'll get the version numbers with that command, so what you'd want to do is:

`rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}\n"`

This will strip off the version numbers and give you just the package name, which will work better in a kickstart.